# can't use alt+ctrl+up/down shortcut in vs-code running on remote computer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Windows10 in my working computer, this shortcut works well when I use VS Code locally.

If I use rdp to remote access my computer, I can't use this shortcut (other shortcuts works well, shift+ctrl+up/down is the only one I have problem until now)

Is it a problem in VS code or in RDP?

Answer (score 0):

Probably with the RPD, if when you use locally there are no problems.
To workaround this, you can add another shortcut to do the same when in remote accesss.

Comment: Thanks.  it is a rdp problem.  https://superuser.com/questions/730050/remote-desktop-does-not-pass-ctrl-alt-up-and-down .  I will create a different combination for this :).